# Event logging in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, logging, doctrine-orm, doctrine

We would like to keep track of all user specific actions regarding the database, e.g. changing the username, getting assigned to a company and so on.

Is there any Symfony bundle that supports this kind of history logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doctrine offers some extensions like timestampable, blameable....

look here : http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html

Every time an entity changes, it must have 'updatedBy' 'updatedAt' field....

(edit : excuse, i changed , first link was in french)

Comment: Nice, thanks. Funny that I didn't come up with this Symfony page when searching for it. I was looking into the [Symfony bundle search page](http://knpbundles.com/) but couldn't find anything there.